# Unexpected behavior in nested recursive function

Tags: perl, recursion, while-loop, vmware

I have some code that behaves rather strangely.

I am inside a function, and I declare a nested one, which should check if something isn't okay. If it's not then it should sleep for five seconds and call itself again.

```
sub stop {

    sub wait_for_stop {
        my $vm_view = shift;

        if ( $vm_view->runtime->powerState->val ne "poweredOff" ) {
            debug("...");
            sleep(5);
            wait_for_stop();
        }
    }

    debug("Waiting for the VM to stop");
    wait_for_stop( @$vm_views[0] );
}
```

So, in the call that results in the recursion inside the `if` condition, if I put the parameter (as the function definition expects it), like this:

```
wait_for_stop($vm_view);
```

I get an infinite loop.

If I leave it without a parameter, as in the code example above, it works as expected.

Shouldn't `$vm_view` in the subsequent calls be empty? Or the last used value (`$vm_view->runtime->powerState->val`)? Either case should result in unexpected behavior and error.

But it works without any parameter. So why is that? Is there something I've missed from perldoc?

*EDIT1:* Actually, the value of `$vm_views` does get changed, so that's not the reason for the infinite loop.

#### General clarifications

I am using the VMware SDK. The `$vm_views` object contains the VM details. I am polling one of its methods to detect a change, in this particular case, I need to know when the machine is turned off. So, for lack of a better way, I make a call every 5 seconds until the value is satisfactory.

My purpose is to stop the VM, make modifications that can only be made while it's off, and then launch it.

#### Actual question

When I don't pass a parameter, the block works as expected – it waits until the value is `poweredOff` (the VM is off), and continues, which doesn't make much sense, at least to me.

In the case I put `$vm_view` as parameter, I get an infinite loop (the value will still get changed, since I'm calling a method).

So I am wondering why the function works, when after the first call, `$vm_view` should be `undef`, and therefore, be stuck in an infinite loop? [undef ne "poweredOff" -> sleep -> recursion till death]

And why, when I pass the expected value, it gets stuck?

PS: To all those saying my recursion is weird and useless in this scenario – due to a myriad of reasons, I need to use such a format (it's better suited for my needs, since, after I get this bit working, I'll modify it to add various stuff and reuse it, and, for what I have in mind, a function seems to be the best option).

Comment: "it works as expected" Does this mean it doesn't give an infinite loop when you don't pass in a parameter?

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), perhaps with a trivially mocked `$vm_view` ?

Comment: This is an odd use of recursion. I think `while ($val ne "poweredOff") { sleep 5; }` is much easier to understand at a glance, and you don't have to worry about deep recursion warnings or eating into the stack. (Of course, you have to actually *do* something with `$val` or you'll get an infinite loop, whether you use recursion or iteration.)

Comment: What value is in `$vm_view` when you call `wait_for_stop();`? Without seeing your whole code, we cannot help. As you saw, most answers just assumed you never updated it. We don't know what's happening in the background.

Comment: *"undef ne "poweredOff" -> sleep -> recursion till death"* That isn't what happens. You have a value of `undef` for `$vm_view`, but you try to call its `runtime` method. That will fail immediately with `Can't call method "runtime" on an undefined value` before it gets anywhere near the comparison. This can't be the code that you're running

Comment: Regarding your choice of recursion, please believe me that it is the *wrong choice*. There is *always* a ways of avoiding recursion, and here it is simply standing in for a `while` loop. Each time a recursive procedure calls itself another stack frame is used up, and if the wait time is long you run the risk of getting an `OUT OF MEMORY!` error which will kill your program. That's aside from it being difficult to read, and (as you have discovered) difficult to get right

Comment: @Borodin, it worked with undef(i mean - i made a print of the value just before the if condition, it printed undef, and then continued looping... i use both warnings and strict).
As for the recursion.. you are right, and i am not fond of it myself(for personal reasons), but it seemed to be the best option for the current code structure i have (i am working with legacy code i have to make minimal changes to and extend with a library), but i think that i can go through the extra length to adopt a nicer, regular loop. Maybe then i won't see such unexpected behavior.

Comment: @PerlDog: You'll be glad to know that I've finished editing my `warnings` statements

Answer (score 2):

You should always look at your standard tools before going for something a little more exotic like recursion. All you need here is a `while` loop

It's also worth noting that `@$vm_views[0]` should be `$$vm_views[0])` or, better, `$vm_views->[0]`. And you don't gain anything by defining a subroutine *inside* another one -- the effect is the same as if it was declared separately afterwards

An infinite loop is what I would expect if `$vm_view->runtime->powerState->val` never returns `poweredOff`, and the code below won't fix that. I don't see any code that tells the VM to stop before you wait for the status change. Is that correct?

I don't understand why you say that your code works correctly when you call `wait_for_stop` without any parameters. You will get the fatal error

```
Can't call method "runtime" on an undefined value
```

and your program will stop. Is what you have posted the real code?

This will do what you intended. I also think it's easier to read

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $vm_views;

sub stop {

    debug ("Waiting for the VM to stop");

    my $vm_view = $vm_views->[0];
    while ( $vm_view->runtime->powerState->val ne 'poweredOff' ) {
        debug('...');
        sleep 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Re "Also, you don't gain anything by defining a subroutine inside another one", I can think of one: headaches. It's indeed a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have a better time not calling `wait_for_stop()` recursively. This way might serve you better:

```
sub stop
{
    sub wait_for_stop
    {
            my $vm_view = shift;
            if ($vm_view->runtime->powerState->val ne "poweredOff")
            {
                    debug("...");
                    #sleep(5);
                    #wait_for_stop();
                    return 0;
            }
            return 1;
    }
    debug ("Waiting for the VM to stop");
    until(wait_for_stop(@$vm_views[0]))
    {
         sleep(5);
    }
}
```

Your old way was rather confusing and I don't think you were passing the `$vm_view` variable through to the recursive subroutine call.

Comment: The OP doesn't want you to improve the code, he wants you to explain the counter-intuitive behavior he's seeing.

Answer (score -1):

Update:

I tried reading it here:
https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/viperltoolkit/doc/perl_toolkit_guide.html#step3

It says:

> When the script is run, the VI Perl Toolkit runtime checks the
>   environment variables, configuration file contents, and command-line
>   entries (in this order) for the necessary connection-setup details. If
>   none of these overrides are available, the runtime uses the defaults
>   (see Table 1 ) to setup the connection.

So, the "runtime" is using the default connection details even when a vm object is not defined? May be?
That still doesn't answer why it doesn't work when the parameter is passed. 
You need to understand the VM SDK better. You logic for recursion and usage of function parameters are fine.

Also, the page: https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/viperltoolkit/doc/perl_toolkit_guide.html

says -

> VI Perl Toolkit views have several characteristics that you should
>   keep in mind as you write your own scripts. Specifically, a view:

- Is a Perl object
- Includes properties and methods that correlate to the properties and
  operations of the server-side managed object
- Is a **static copy** of one or more server-side managed objects, and as
  such (static), is not updated automatically as the state of objects
  on the server changes.

So what the "vm" function returns is a static copy, which can be updated from the script. May be it is getting updated when you make a call while passing the $vm_view?

Old Answer:
Problem is not what you missed from Perl docs. The problem is with your understanding of recursion.

The purpose of recursion is to keep running until $vm_view->runtime->powerState->val becomes "PoweredOff" and then cascade back. If you don't update the value, it keeps running forever.

When you say:

> I get an infinite loop.

Are you updating the `$vm_view` within the if condition?
Otherwise, the variable is same every time you call the function and hence you can end up in infinite loop.

> If I leave it without a parameter, as in the code example above, it
>   works as expected.

How can it work as expected? What is expected? There is no way the function can know what value your $vm_view is being updated with.

I have simplified the code, added updating a simple variable (similar to your $vm_view) and tested. Use this to understand what is happening:

```
sub wait_for_stop
{
    my $vm_view = shift;

    if ($vm_view < 10){
        print "debug...\n";
        sleep(5);
        $vm_view++; // update $vm_view->runtime->powerState->val here
                    // so that it becomes "poweredOff" at some point of time
                    // and breaks the recursion
        wait_for_stop($vm_view);
    }
}

wait_for_stop(1);
```

Let me know in comments how the variable is being updated and I will help resolve.

Comment: "Otherwise, the variable is same every time you call the function and hence you can end up in infinite loop." `$vm_view->runtime->powerState->val` will not necessarily have the same value in each iteration. `val` is a method, so it could be returning a different value with each invocation, for example `return time();` or `return rand();`

Comment: Of course, if `$vm_view` is undefined, no method will be called at all.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot is correct, i am calling a method, so the value gets changed(eventually), what i am trying to catch with my code. 
As for what is "expected", i am trying to detect when the value has changed to what i need(poweredOff), so i am calling the method every 5 seconds. And the infinite loop occurs only when i pass the parameter. It works when the value would be undef(no parameter passed to function)/ 
PS: Check the update on the post

Comment: Pardon for being so narrow. I have added an update. Thanks @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, for correcting my view.

Comment: @Chandar Kakarlapudi The SDK documentation could be a little misleading. I have performed a check(priny on everry loop) and the value does get updated. The problem is, after it does, nothing happens(it just hangs there and doesn't continue, nor does it loop anymore - i was mistaken that i had an infinite loop, i actually have a very long loop and then nothing)

Comment: That's strange... Is the number of times it is looping (before it hangs) fixed every time you run it? Or is it random? (Wondering if there is anything to do with memory or limit on number of calls or hardware etc.)

Comment: It seems to be rather similar, but it loops until a virtual machine has booted successfully, which is more or less a static value.